# Angular2- Catch error and display it in view

Tags: angular, api, exception

I have a service that performs get request and throws the error.

**service.ts**

```
 return this.http.get(/apiUrl)
 .map(
    (response: Response) => {
        const items = response.json();
        return items;
    })
    .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
         return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

I subscribe it to the component and I want to display the error in view. I searched for this exception handling but I couldnot get relevant answers how do I do it?

**component.ts**

```
this.faqService.getServers()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
        this.item = data.items;
        console.log(this.item);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
});
```

I can see the error in console how to display it in the view.

**error**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign to a variable and then display

declare a variable in your ts

```
errorMessage : string;
```

and then,

```
this.faqService.getServers()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
        this.item = data.items;
        console.log(this.item);
        },
        (error) => {
        this.errorMessage= error.error_message;             
        }
    );
});
```

and then in HTML

```
<h1>{{errorMessage}}</h1>
```

You need to return the error from your service,

```
 return this.http.get(/url)
     .map(
        (response: Response) => {           
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(
            (error: Response) => {
             return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
    }
```

Comment: I want to display the body of the error as I mentioned in the image.

Comment: Response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL: https://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/search/advanced?key=uBSdSxUAOFTTBe5jSIdq9Q((&access_token=&/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=True&title=erwe&site=stackoverflow&filter=!*L7QmTklW(QkSp_f  **I get this as the errorMessage not the _body**

Comment: you need to return the error from service as explained above

Comment: @Sammy did it help

Answer (score 3):

**Service.ts** 
your service should be like

```
return this.http.get(/apiUrl)
 .map(
    (response: Response) => {
        const items = response.json();
        return items;
    })
    .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
         return Observable.throw(error.json());
    });
}
```

your component should be like.
**Component**

```
errorMessage : string;

this.faqService.getServers()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
        this.item = data.items;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.errorMessage = error.error_message;
        }
    );
});
```

**html**

```
<span class="alert">{{errorMessage}}</span>
```