# Angular http client retryWhen cannot catch the error on the caller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic3, httpclient

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) and I have an **API** call which is a **GET** request to the **server**. When the first try fails I will call the `retryWhen` is something error goes on.

The problem is that I couldn't catch the **error** to the **caller**

Here is my **service** code below.

```
getDriverMeInfo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.global.baseUrl}/me`)
    .retryWhen(err => err.delay(10000).take(10)) // Delay after 10 seconds when an error occured and retry maximum of 10 takes
    .concat(Observable.throw(new Error('Retry limit exceeded!'))).toPromise()
  }
```

The **component** code below which is the **caller**

```
async getDriverInfo() {
    try {
      const meDetails = await this.driverMe.getDriverMeInfo() // Get the profile information of the driver if
      console.log(meDetails)
    } catch (err) { 
      console.log(err) // This wouldn't catch the error on the HttpErrorResponse
    } 
  }
```

The only thing I catch in the error is the `Observable.throw(new Error('Retry limit exceeded!'))` but the instance of `HttpErrorResponse` that will give me a **status code** or **message** why it **failed** can't be catch.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  getDriverMeInfo()
  {
    return this._http.get<any>(`${this.global.baseUrl}/me`)
    .retryWhen((err)=>
    {
      return err.scan((retryCount)=>{
        retryCount+=1;
        if(retryCount<6)
        {
          console.log("retrying attemp: "+ retryCount);
          return retryCount
        }
        else
        {
          throw(err)
        }
      },0).delay(10000)
    })
  }
```

and the component,

```
this.driverMe.getDriverMeInfo().subscribe(res=>{    
})
```

Comment: 21 hours remaining :(

Comment: Haha ok. I was kidding , let it comes whenever it is

Comment: You waited for this. Hahaha sorry btw. Thanks!

Comment: Btw sometimes when the server return a response code of 500. It sais that err.scan is not a function.

Comment: you can handle error in that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973295/angular2-catch-error-and-display-it-in-view

Comment: Sorrry it didn't help me.

Comment: Oh what happened?

Comment: The reference question that the link you gave. Want's to display the error in the view. In my case when an error occured in the http request. It sais that `err.scan` is not a function.

Comment: can I discuss with u in the chat? Sorry for bothering.